# To infinity and back

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, libc

There are mathematical operations that yield real numbers from +/- infinity. For example `exp(-infinity) = 0`. Is there a standard for mathematical functions in the standard `C` library that accept IEEE-754 infinities (without throwing, or returning NaN). I am on a linux system and would be interested in such a list for `glibc`. I could not find such a list in their online manual. For instance their documentation on `exp` does not mention how it handles the `-infinity` case. Any  help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `exp(-infinity)`? Did it throw? Did it get NaN or 0?

Comment: +1 even just for the title :-)

Comment: The language standard does not say anything about whether infinity is a representable value, so surely this is up to the implementation.

Comment: @Anders that example worked but want to know how portable it would be. I would be happy with POSIX say

Comment: @srean: POSIX [`exp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/exp.html) guarantees +0 for -Inf.

Comment: @Mat oh thanks. I will need a few other functions would it be possible for you to point me to a list. And if you can add it as an answer so that we can vote it up

Comment: ¤ There are two aspects to IEEE 754: binary representation, and semantics. If `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` yields `true`, then the intended meaning is that you can assume both representation and semantics. But in practice you can only assume the representation (e.g. consider g++ option `--fastmath`, IIRC). So as @KerrekSB notes, you'll have to check the implementation's documentation. Or just try out things. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @srean: I don't know of a list - that's a rather strange request you have. Just look up the docs for either POSIX or your implementation (you'll need to check on each platform you're targetting anyway)

Comment: @Mat I did not realize that you already pointed me to a link. GCC's texinfo manual did not have these details so was asking for a place to look those up. Now I have it. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *See Also* section of [POSIX' math.h definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html#tag_13_26) links to the POSIX definitions of acceptable domains.

E.g. [`fabs()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fabs.html):

```
If x is ±0, +0 shall be returned.
If x is ±Inf, +Inf shall be returned.
```

---

I converted mentioned *See Also*-section to StackOverflow-Markdown:

[acos()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/acos.html), 
[acosh()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/acosh.html), 
[asin()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/asin.html), 
[atan()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atan.html), 
[atan2()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atan2.html), 
[cbrt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/cbrt.html), 
[ceil()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ceil.html), 
[cos()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/cos.html), 
[cosh()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/cosh.html), 
[erf()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/erf.html), 
[exp()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exp.html), 
[expm1()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/expm1.html), 
[fabs()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fabs.html), 
[floor()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/floor.html), 
[fmod()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmod.html), 
[frexp()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/frexp.html), 
[hypot()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hypot.html), 
[ilogb()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ilogb.html), 
[isnan()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isnan.html), 
[j0()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/j0.html), 
[ldexp()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ldexp.html), 
[lgamma()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lgamma.html), 
[log()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/log.html), 
[log10()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/log10.html), 
[log1p()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/log1p.html), 
[logb()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/logb.html), 
[modf()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/modf.html), 
[nextafter()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nextafter.html), 
[pow()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pow.html), 
[remainder()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/remainder.html), 
[rint()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rint.html), 
[scalb()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scalb.html), 
[sin()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sin.html), 
[sinh()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sinh.html), 
[sqrt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sqrt.html), 
[tan()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tan.html), 
[tanh()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tanh.html), 
[y0()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/y0.html),

*I contributed search/replace/regex-fu. We now just need someone with cURL-fu.*

Comment: Oh man ! I guess I should have said "now that I have the url I dont need the list. I can look up the functions I use". But thanks a lot, feeling bad that I made you look all that stuff up.

Comment: @srean: That's okay, it's useful for myself :)

Comment: If you want these all in one tidy place, the posix edge cases are (almost) all inherited from Annex F of the C standard.

Comment: @Stephen: Cool, I didn't know that. It is over my fu though to convert them to Markdown in a lazy manner.

Answer (score 9):

In C99 it's on Appendix F:

```
F.9.3.1 The exp functions
-- exp(±0) returns 1.
-- exp(-∞) returns +0.
-- exp(+∞) returns +∞.
```

Appendix F is normative and:

> An implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` shall conform to the specifications in this annex.